# Search and Replace .xml using (Super) Sed

Tags: xml, search, replace, sed

I'm trying to use sed to change a string in large paragraph in an .xml file.

name="m_AllowDownload">False<

I was trying to use this line to replace the False with True.

```
s/name="m_AllowDownload">False</name="m_AllowDownload">True</ old_file >new_file
```

It works if I just target words like False but when I add the symbols it doesn't. There are many occurrences of false so I have to be more specific than targeting that. I'm running this under the super sed executable from command line. Sorry I'm really new to this any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because shell interprets your `<` and `>` as redirections. To avoid it you need to add `'` before and after sed command:

```
sed 's/name="m_AllowDownload">False</name="m_AllowDownload">True</'
```

or `"` :

```
sed "s/name=\"m_AllowDownload\">False</name=\"m_AllowDownload\">True</"
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. I had tried it with the single quotes but the supersed.exe bug's with that format. The " quote marks work perfect though!